# Show content of File

Tags: java, servlets

i would like to open/show the file content in a browser but i dosen't work.
This is my code:

```
 @WebServlet("/Download")
public class Download extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String name = request.getParameter("id");
    String sep = File.separator;
    File file = new File("C:" + sep + "FILE" + sep + name);

    if(!file.exists())
    {
        response.getWriter().print("File not found");
        return;
    }


    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int i = 0;
    while((i = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    { 
        baos.write(buffer, 0, i);

    }


     response.setContentType("application/pdf");
     response.setContentLength(baos.size());
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=help.pdf");
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "cache, must-revalidate");
     response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    in.close();

    baos.writeTo(bos);
    baos.flush();
    bos.flush(); 
    bos.close();


  }

}
```

I try to open that file with a servlet class.
I browser debugger i can see that response is coming in, usually in this format(JVBERi0xLjMNMSAwIG9iag08PC9UeXBl...).

Thanks for helping me

**EDIT**

on the jsp site i call the servlet with an AJAX call, looks like this where 'id' is the fileName which the user want to open.

```
function downloadFile(id) {

$.ajax({
    url:"Download",
    type:"POST",
    data:"id="+id       
});
```

}

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: look up on the web server log file. Supposedly, you are likely to get the HTML error code different from 200 (that's an ok response to the html request). If you get a 404, that means the request is forbidden, possibly due to a file permission.

Comment: you should show the response somewhere in jsp!! you are not using ajax success function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should add this code inside your `ajax` call in `downloadFile(id)` function.

```
success:function(response){
            $("#<Some_SPAN_OR_TextAreaID>").show();               
            $("#<Some_SPAN_OR_TextAreaID").html(response.responseText);
        }
```